# Graphical audio routing for PulseAudio (QJackCtl equivalent)

Tags: linux, audio, audio-recording

For [JACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit), there is a GUI application called [QJackCtl](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/) that lets you graphically route audio from sinks to sources in arbitrarily complex ways, especially when used in conjunction with additional mixers (e.g. [jack_mixer](https://github.com/jack-mixer/jack_mixer)):

[image: Example of routing in QJackCtl]

I'm wondering whether something like this exists for [PulseAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio). I know that the basic building blocks for it are there (e.g. PulseAudio already lets you send audio from/to different applications to/from different sinks/sources, using pavucontrol or pactl), but what I'm missing is this graph-like view, with nodes and edges representing sinks/sources/mixers and connections, respectively.

The reason I'm asking is that I don't need JACK's realtime capabilities and running a hybrid PulseAudio/JACK setup is not only a waste of resources but also makes this kind of routing more cumbersome (as you have to set appropriate inputs/outputs both in pavucontrol and in QJackCtl). A pure-PulseAudio solution would be much nicer.

Slightly related to that (but not as important) is the question whether something like jack_mixer (linked above) exists for PulseAudio, which would present itself as several sinks and a source and allows the user to mix the incoming streams into an outgoing one, with a GUI for volume levels. pavucontrol by itself does *not* fit the bill, as it only allows setting volume levels for different streams "globally", not locally for just a specific mixing output.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question because I finally found something: [pagraphcontrol](https://github.com/futpib/pagraphcontrol) seems like exactly what I'm looking for.

[image: pagraphcontrol example showing complex audio routing setup as graph]